# OS X Command-line URL filter

Tags: macos, command-line

I have a bash script that uses bash's "read" builtin to obtain a username and password from the user and then uses them as part of an AFP URL. I'm encountering some problems, however, when passwords contain characters that affect URL parsing (';' for example).

I've looked around for a command-line utility that can do URL-filtering but haven't found one. Does anybody know of such a utility? I would like to be able to do something like the following:

mount_afp "afp://`` ` ``urlfilter $USER`` ` ``:`` ` ``urlfilter $PASS`` ` ``@server.com".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple one-line Python script to do this:

```
echo $USER | python -c 'import urllib; print urllib.quote(raw_input())'
```

Note that, while acceptable for your usage, `urllib.quote` is designed for use on URL components, not the entire URL.  See [#120951](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120951/how-can-i-normalize-a-url-in-python) for more.