# Function in Python to clean up and normalize a URL

Tags: python, url

I am using URLs as a key so I need them to be consistent and clean. I need a python function that will take a URL and clean it up so that I can do a get from the DB. For example, it will take the following:

```
example.com
example.com/
http://example.com/
http://example.com
http://example.com?
http://example.com/?
http://example.com//
```

and output a clean consistent version:

```
http://example.com/
```

I looked through std libs and GitHub and couldn't find anything like this

**Update**

I couldn't find a Python library that implements everything discussed here and in the RFC:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization

So I am writing one now. There is a lot more to this than I initially imagined.

Comment: The standardized cleaned up form should be `http://example.com/` rather than `http://example.com`, an HTTP URL without a path component is technically not well formed.

Comment: You need to define clean. Does it mean an absolute URL? Or a canonical URL?

Comment: What I really mean is normalize, which is the word that didn't really come to me when I typed this up at 5am. The urlparse() looks like what I want, I didn't notice the normalizing aspects of that function when I was reading through the docs early this morning.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371992/comparing-two-urls-in-python/18690955#18690955

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I normalize a URL in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120951/how-can-i-normalize-a-url-in-python)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [`urlparse.urlparse()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html). I've had good success with it.

---

*note*: This answer is from 2011 and is specific to Python2. In Python3 the `urlparse` module has been named to `urllib.parse`.  The corresponding Python3 documentation for `urllib.parse` can be found here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: Along with urlparse.urlunparse().

Comment: Thanks for that - for some reason I missed the normalization aspect of that function when I was reading the docs early this morning. Took me a few minutes to implement

Comment: scratch that - the normalization fails on 70%+ of my test cases (I have 50 tests now). For some reason the python community was against implementing normalization per the RFC and per how browsers handle it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization

I found this python bug:

http://bugs.python.org/issue4191

Comment: to add, the urlparse normalization will not find those above URL's in the question to all be equal to each other, which is what is important.

Comment: The Link is dead

Comment: It doesn't clean certain cases like : `print(urlparse.urlparse('http://example.com//episode/').geturl())`. At least, it didn't clean out the `//` in the url in Python 2

Answer (score 9):

It's done in [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/):

http://nullege.com/codes/search/scrapy.utils.url.canonicalize_url

> Canonicalize the given url by applying the following procedures:
>
> - sort query arguments, first by key, then by value
> - percent encode paths and query arguments. non-ASCII characters are   percent-encoded using UTF-8 (RFC-3986)
> - normalize all spaces (in query arguments) '+' (plus symbol)
> - normalize percent encodings case (%2f -> %2F)
> - remove query arguments with blank values (unless keep_blank_values is True)
> - remove fragments (unless keep_fragments is True)

Comment: At least these days Scrapy imports this function from the [w3lib package](http://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/w3lib.html#w3lib.url.canonicalize_url).

Answer (score 1):

[url-normalize](https://pypi.org/project/url-normalize/) might be what you're looking for.

Depending on your preference you can also probably:

1. remove [UTM parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_parameters)
2. remove `http(s)://`
3. remove `www.`
4. remove trailing `/`

here is an example which does this:

```
from w3lib.url import url_query_cleaner
from url_normalize import url_normalize

urls = ['example.com',
'example.com/',
'http://example.com/',
'http://example.com',
'http://example.com?',
'http://example.com/?',
'http://example.com//',
'http://example.com?utm_source=Google']


def canonical_url(u):
    u = url_normalize(u)
    u = url_query_cleaner(u,parameterlist = ['utm_source','utm_medium','utm_campaign','utm_term','utm_content'],remove=True)

    if u.startswith("http://"):
        u = u[7:]
    if u.startswith("https://"):
        u = u[8:]
    if u.startswith("www."):
        u = u[4:]
    if u.endswith("/"):
        u = u[:-1]
    return u

list(map(canonical_url,urls))
```

Which gives this result:

```
['example.com',
 'example.com',
 'example.com',
 'example.com',
 'example.com',
 'example.com',
 'example.com',
 'example.com']
```

There are still issues with shortened links and redirects of various sorts but you'd need to make a request to the url to sort through those.

Answer (score -5):

Have you considered using regular xpressions? They will help you check for malformed URLs. I have used this in one of my applications

"^[, .a-zA-Z0-9]*$"

Comment: It does not answer the question.