# Comparing two urls in Python

Tags: python, url

Is there a standard way to compare two urls in Python - that implements `are_url_the_same` in this example:

```
url_1 = 'http://www.foo.com/bar?a=b&c=d'
url_2 = 'http://www.foo.com:80/bar?c=d;a=b'

if are_urls_the_same(url_1, url2):
    print "URLs are the same"
```

By the same I mean that they access the same resource - so the two urls in the example are the same.

Comment: While the hostnames are equivalent, due to HTTP defaulting to port 80, the querystrings are completely different.

Comment: It is not strictly true that reordering the query params must result in the same resource.  Order is observable, and may be apparent to some (pathalogical) services.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a simple class that enables you to do this:

```
if Url(url1) == Url(url2):
    pass
```

It could easily be revamped as a function, though these objects are hashable, and therefore enable you to add them into a cache using a set or dictionary:

```
# Python 2
# from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qsl
# from urllib import unquote_plus
# Python 3
from urllib.parse import urlparse, parse_qsl, unquote_plus
    
class Url(object):
    '''A url object that can be compared with other url orbjects
    without regard to the vagaries of encoding, escaping, and ordering
    of parameters in query strings.'''

    def __init__(self, url):
        parts = urlparse(url)
        _query = frozenset(parse_qsl(parts.query))
        _path = unquote_plus(parts.path)
        parts = parts._replace(query=_query, path=_path)
        self.parts = parts

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.parts == other.parts

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.parts)
```

Comment: `from urllib import unquote_plus` is missing from above. Otherwise this code is pretty cool ! Thanks - it saved me a bunch of time !

Comment: Almost perfect. Need to consider that path `'/foo'` and `'/foo/'` are the same as well (and also `''` and `'/'` of course).

Comment: MaratC `/foo` and `/foo/` are most certainly NOT the same. And `''` does not exist as the browser changes it to `/` but the browser does not change `/foo` to `/foo/` and can refer to different things (i.e. a file foo vs a directory foo).

Answer (score 10):

Use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) and write a comparison function with the fields that you need

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('http://www.cwi.nl:80/%7Eguido/Python.html')
```

And you can compare on any of the following:

1. scheme   0   URL scheme specifier
2. netloc   1   Network location part
3. path 2   Hierarchical path
4. params   3   Parameters for last path element
5. query    4   Query component
6. fragment 5   Fragment identifier
7. username     User name
8. password     Password
9. hostname     Host name (lower case)
10. port     Port number as integer, if present

Comment: Good solution. You just have to choose which of those ten elements need to be equal for them to be deemed the same.

Comment: Do I really need to roll my own and consider all the edge cases - is there nothing like Perl's URI::eq (http://search.cpan.org/dist/URI/URI.pm)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a third party library, try [yarl](https://github.com/aio-libs/yarl/).

I found the following case where the top answer fails:

```py
>>> import yarl
>>> yarl.URL("http://example.com/path/../to") == yarl.URL("http://example.com/to")
True
```