# Amazon S3 Python S3Boto 403 Forbidden When Signature Has '+' sign

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

I am using `Django` and `S3Boto` and whenever a signature has a `'+'` sign in it, I get a `403 Forbidden`. If there is no `'+'` sign in the signature, I get the resource just fine. What could be wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

The repo is at : https://github.com/boto/boto

the files concerned are:

```
boto/utils.py
boto/s3/connection.py
```

**NOTE:**
I am quite new to Python. I tried modifying the code but I still can't get the encoding done properly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with S3Boto, but my gut instinct would be something isn't getting URL encoded correctly, so the + is getting decoded as a space.

Comment: here is the issue I created: https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/916 . If you like to see the code, clone the repo and look at boto.s3.connection in the generate_url method. that seems to be where the encoding is done. I have done this but I can't find where the error is T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, the problem is not in S3Boto but in some call to "unquote" that happens later on the url.

I answered a similar question here:

[Inconsistent SignatureDoesNotMatch Amazon S3 with django-pipeline, s3boto and storages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820566/inconsistent-signaturedoesnotmatch-amazon-s3-with-django-pipeline-s3boto-and-st/12262106#comment16459418_12262106)

Please check out my solution there.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little short on time (as it's 1:30am) so unfortunately I do not have a code sample for you yet, but I believe this is because the value + in a URL should be encoded. So from github, your url of...

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dragonflysco/static/js/plugins/blockui.js?Signature=+tahbTacs5Vkzt5jQ+hZULzGPhE=&Expires=1345019173&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJNCPYIZVZXKOPCHA
```

should really be

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/dragonflysco/static/js/plugins/blockui.js?Signature=%2BtahbTacs5Vkzt5jQ+hZULzGPhE=&Expires=1345019173&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJNCPYIZVZXKOPCHA
```

(Note: I replaced the + with %2B)

See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

To fix the code, I would add an URLEncoding function where it builds the URL query string.

Comment: however, I am using a plugin, and I tried digging into that plugin's source but I can't find the code that encodes the signature and makes the request. If you look at the comment above, I have created the issue and tried changing the encoding at some places, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I just committed what I hope will be a fix for this issue in boto.  See https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/a01a5d1a1e88f79ed5db52639d3674d9eb5e45dc.  Please let me know if this takes care of the problem.

Comment: So, what part didn't work.  Are you still getting "+" signs in your signatures?

Comment: Are you sure that S3Boto is picking up the new version of boto?  I'm having a hard time figuring out how you could still be getting a "+" in the signature with the latest code.

Comment: I just checked my virtualenv site-packages and the boto plugin. I checked your changes to boto/s3/connection.py and the line you committed is indeed there.

Comment: just to inform you though, I don't get '+' characters in the signature when I use Amazon's old S3 library bundled with django-storages 1.1.4. I examined the code and it seems to return the encoded canonical string with the encode() method that does both b64 encoding, with even an optional url encoding, so quote_plus wasn't a necessity. That may mean something may have gone wrong with the signing of the string in boto/auth.py

Comment: Okay, thanks for the additional information.  I'm have been unable to reproduce this but I'll keep investigating.  It sounds like something is not right.

Comment: a question I asked is related to this, you can see it here(I'll try to apply this and get back to you): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820566/inconsistent-signaturedoesnotmatch-amazon-s3-with-django-pipeline-s3boto-and-st/12262106#12262106