# AWS S3 returns 403 intermittently even for valid resources

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ember.js

I store thumbnail profile pictures of users on S3 and I need to show several (~10) profile pictures at the same time. However the request throws a 403 for about a few of those images. When I retry it errors on some other images. The images shown/not shown are never consistent. What could be the reason for this? Is there a cap on the number of requests and if there is, what would be the best practice in this case?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inconsistent SignatureDoesNotMatch Amazon S3 with django-pipeline, s3boto and storages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820566/inconsistent-signaturedoesnotmatch-amazon-s3-with-django-pipeline-s3boto-and-st)

Comment: Figured out the issue is with this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820566/inconsistent-signaturedoesnotmatch-amazon-s3-with-django-pipeline-s3boto-and-st

Answer (score -1):

403 Status code is Forbidden. You will get this code if you try to access a file that has not been set to public without access keys. You may also get this code if the file is owned by another user and you dont have permission to access it.