# Problems serving staticfiles(css and javascripts) on django project using digital ocean spaces

Tags: python, django, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

i built a project using django 4.2 and i configured django storage and digital ocean spaces on it. the project is also hosted on digital ocean using droplets. the problem i'm having now is that i'm able to collect static and all files are uploaded to digital ocean space, the images are displaying but it doesn't serve the css and javascript. i've been on this for over 2 weeks checking many suggestions online but none of them solved my problem. Below is my current configuration for django 4.2.

please kindly help if you come across this.

This is my current configuration. my media folder resides in my static folder as well.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('aws_s3_access_key')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('aws_s3_secret_key')

AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = env('aws_s3_region_name')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('aws_storage_bucket_name')
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = "https://mogdynamics.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com"

AWS_STATIC_LOCATION = 'static'
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = "public-read"
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}


# DIGITIALOCEAN SPACES CONFIGURATION
STORAGES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3.S3Storage",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "bucket_name": AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
            "region_name": AWS_S3_REGION_NAME,
            "default_acl":  AWS_DEFAULT_ACL
        },
    },
    "staticfiles": {
        "BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3.S3Storage",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "bucket_name": AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME,
            "region_name": AWS_S3_REGION_NAME,
            "default_acl":  AWS_DEFAULT_ACL
        },
    },
}


STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL}/{AWS_STATIC_LOCATION}/'
```

When i viewed the page source and clicked on the css link i get the below error

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message/>
<RequestId>tx000003614bd933f0201e8-00657ea2de-4e1a3-nyc3d</RequestId>
<HostId>4e1a3-nyc3d-nyc3-zg04</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inconsistent SignatureDoesNotMatch Amazon S3 with django-pipeline, s3boto and storages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820566/inconsistent-signaturedoesnotmatch-amazon-s3-with-django-pipeline-s3boto-and-st)

Comment: Thanks for your response @IvanStarostin this doesn’t answer my question.