# python: encode a url with percentage signs?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert the following url

```
http://www.website.com/search/si/1/doctors/Vancouver, BC
```

to

```
http://www.website.com/search/si/1/doctors/Vancouver%2C%20BC
```

I tried

```
urllib.quote('http://www.website.com/search/si/1/doctors/Vancouver, BC', '')
```

and it resulted in replacing everything with a percentage sign.

What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`urllib.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) for the url `path` leaving everything else as is:

```
from urllib import quote
from urlparse import urlparse, urlunparse

url = "http://www.website.com/search/si/1/doctors/Vancouver, BC"

scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment = urlparse(url)
path = quote(path)
print urlunparse((scheme, netloc, path, params, query, fragment))
```

prints:

```
http://www.website.com/search/si/1/doctors/Vancouver%2C%20BC
```

See also:

- [How can I normalize a URL in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120951/how-can-i-normalize-a-url-in-python)

Comment: omg....finally a real answer

Comment: No, not a real answer: imagine you have a `:` in the query string: `'http://www.website.com/Vancouver:BC'`.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh good point, what about now?

Comment: @alecxe Now perfect. I wonder if this can't be done with one function.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh yup, `werkzeug` helps not to reinvent the wheel here , see [`url_fix()`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/urls.py#L481-L497).

Answer (score 0):

```
urllib.quote('www.website.com/search/si/1/doctors/Vancouver, BC')
```

without the second parameter AND without the protocol part `http://`. The second parameter is a list of safe characters NOT to be replaced, default is `'/'`, which is OK in your case.

Comment: this gives me `http%3A//www.website.com/search/si/1/doctors/Vancouver%2C%20BC`

Comment: You should use the path part without the protocol part. Otherwise it thinks that what you want to fetch is http://http%3A//www.website.com/search/si/1/doctors/Vancouver%2C%20BC.

Comment: You can use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) to separate the path from the URL.

Comment: This can work for you: `urllib.quote(url, '/:'])`