# How to handle links containing space between them in Python

Tags: python, url, request, broken-links

I am trying to extract links from a webpage and then open them in my web browser. My Python program is able to successfully extract the links, but some links have spaces between them which cannot be open using `request module`.

For example `example.com/A, B C` it will not open using the request module. But if I convert it into `example.com/A,%20B%20C` it will open. Is there a simple way in python to fill the spaces with `%20` ?

```
`http://example.com/A, B C` ---> `http://example.com/A,%20B%20C`
```

I want to convert all links which have spaces between them into the above format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`urlencode` actually takes a dictionary, for example:

```
>>> urllib.urlencode({'test':'param'})
'test=param'`
```

You actually need something like this:

```
import urllib
import urlparse

def url_fix(s, charset='utf-8'):
    if isinstance(s, unicode):
        s = s.encode(charset, 'ignore')
    scheme, netloc, path, qs, anchor = urlparse.urlsplit(s)
    path = urllib.quote(path, '/%')
    qs = urllib.quote_plus(qs, ':&=')
    return urlparse.urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path, qs, anchor))
```

Then:

```
>>>url_fix('http://example.com/A, B C')    
'http://example.com/A%2C%20B%20C'
```

Taken from [How can I normalize a URL in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120951/how-can-i-normalize-a-url-in-python)

Comment: I am using something like this `'%20'.join(line.split())`. Do you think it is a good decision ?

Comment: Well that will handle the spaces :) But I would recommend using the above snippet, since it appears to work rather well. The commas are also not supported in http urls, as well as a list of other characters. This appears to handle them correctly.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Thank you so much :)

Comment: This won't work in python3 as urlparse & urllib are combined into one and encoding to Unicode is not required as every string is considered as unicode in python 3. Check my last post on this page.

Answer (score 1):

use url encode:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlencode(yourstring)
```

Comment: I am getting this error `TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object`

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 working solution for [@rofls](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318734/rofls) answer.

```
import urllib.parse as urlparse
def url_fix(s):
    scheme, netloc, path, qs, anchor = urlparse.urlsplit(s)
    path = urlparse.quote(path, '/%')
    qs = urlparse.quote_plus(qs, ':&=')
    return urlparse.urlunsplit((scheme, netloc, path, qs, anchor))
```