# How to make a scrapy request on a url that have more then one parameter?

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to make a request using scrap shell first, just to test the Xpaths to this kind of url:

```
site.com/search/?action=search&description=MY SEARCH &e_author=
```

but the requests only goes to 'action=search' ... the other parameters is been requested ..

how do I build this requests?

Comment: Have you tried using quotes while opening it from scrapy shell ?
`scrapy shell "site.com/search/?action=search&description=MY SEARCH &e_author="`

Comment: yeah using quotes should work

Answer (score 1):

You have to *normalize the URL before making a request*, see:

- [How can I normalize a URL in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120951/how-can-i-normalize-a-url-in-python)

I would go with [`urllib.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote):

```
> import urllib

> quoted_url = urllib.quote(url)
> fetch(quoted_url)
```